# Java Simple Way to Create Application Singleton

Tags: java, singleton

I am trying to create a global connection pool for my Java app.

My problem is that when I use the following approach:

```
package mypackage;

public class Singleton
{
    private static MyPool connPool;

    private Singleton() {}

    public MyPool getPool() {
        if (connPool == null)
           connPool = new MyPool();
        return connPool;
    }
}
```

Now if I have two classes A and B which import Singleton class above using

```
import mypackage.Singleton;
```

Then I will end up invoking `new MyPool()` twice, which means I will open double the connections to my resource (such as database). How can I ensure that I only create the pool one time in my application?

I found some complicated ways of accomplishing this on the internet using reflection. Is there an easier (and/or better) way?

Comment: Just use an `enum`.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton

Comment: How will your classes end up calling new MyPool() twice, if we are not concerned about thread-safety here?

Comment: Each `import` will load Singleton class and get its own copy of `connPool` initialized to `null` so it will get initialized again each time.

Comment: Your implementation of Singleton is totally off-track to me. Please check my answer for corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a thread-safe implementation of a Singleton class here. Of course, the way to achieve this is using enums, but for your case, you can implement double-check locking to ensure no two threads can call new MyPool() simultaneously.

Also, I think in your code, you are actually implementing a factory class, not really a singleton. Your MyPool is a different class than Singleton, which could have a public constructor.

I have made the appropriate changes with comments.

Double check-locking basically just checks the thread-safety before and after null-check, because the whole method is not synchronized, so two threads can indeed get the null value in the condition even after synchronization block, hence the second synchronization.

Also, I think your getPool() should be **static**. You won't be able to call getPool() without an explicit object of Singleton, which I think you don't need.

Corrected version:

```
package mypackage;

public class Singleton{
    // Instance should be of type Singleton, not MyPool
    private static Singleton connPool;

    private Singleton() {}

    // *static* factory method
    public static Singleton getPool() {
        
        // Double-check-locking start
        synchronized(Singleton.class){
            if (connPool == null){
            
                // Double-check-locking end
                synchronized(Singleton.class){
                    
                    //create Singleton instance, not MyPool
                    connPool = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return connPool;
    }
}
```